# some ui updates can run on Non_UI thread in special condition

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

why some ui updates can run  on Non_UI  thread in special condition?
for example:

```
Textview textView;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    new Thread() {
       textView.setText("i can change the textview's text");
    }.start();
 }
```

i'm confused when android to check if the ui action is running on the UI thread? some time later?

Answer (score 0):

remembre that **the only thread** who can change the UI is the UIThread, 
so if you want to change your UI from another thread , you sould use the method `runOnUIThread()`  like this :

```
YourAcitivity.this.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
textView.setText("i can change the textview's text");
}
});
```

**SECOND POINT :** : in your thread , there is **no** method `run()`

Comment: sorry, i missed run method. but new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        textView.setText("i can change the textview's text");
    }
}.start();but this also works fines.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually setting the text in the other thread. The code to run in the new thread goes in the `run` method, which you should implement. Here is the correct syntax:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run(){
        textView.setText("i can change the textview's text");
    }
}.start();
```